# Sort arrays inside an array using a common key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array of arrays,

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => AP-2 (1)
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => AC-1 (2)
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [title] => AB-3 (1)
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [title] => AD-2 (3)
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [title] => AE-2 (1)
    )

),
```

and I need to sort it in a way in which it will look like this,

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => AB-3 (1)
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => AC-1 (2)
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [title] => AD-2 (3)
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [title] => AE-2 (1)
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [title] => AP-2 (1)
    )

)
```

What happened here is basically, sort the arrays using the `title` key alphabetically or maybe sort it using `natsort()` or `natcasesort()`. How would I actually do the sorting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Implement your own swap(ele1, ele2) function and then implement a sorting algorithm of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sorter($key){
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}
usort($arr, sorter('title'));
var_dump($arr);
```

For versions of PHP prior to 5.3, use:

```
function sorter($arr, $index) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $arr2[$key] = strtolower($value[$index]);
    }
    asort($arr2);
    foreach($arr2 as $key =>$value) {
        $arr3[] = $arr[$key];
    }
    return $arr3;
}
var_dump(sorter($arr, 'title'));
```

Comment: @CHiRiLo - I ran the code, and it didn't give me any syntax error. The output is shown above.

Comment: @CHiRiLo - `$a` and `$b` represent the arrays with numerical keys such as `[0] => array('id' => 3, '$title' => 'AB-3')`. On each comparison `$a` and `$b` will represent different arrays, comparing the string value of "title."

Comment: Am I doing this the right way, I assigned the first array above to a variable called `$arr`, then in your solution, I only replaced `$row_array` with `$arr`. Was that the right way to do it?

Comment: It only works 5.3 and above due to closure usage.

Comment: I changed the version of my php to 5.3 and then it magically worked. Whew. Thanks @Jack and also thank you Pé de Leão.

Comment: ahm, @Jack and Pé de Leão, is there another way in which I can make this work using php versions lower than 5.3? The case is that, I can't readily change the php version the web server my client is using so my alternative is that I will find a solution which works on at least version 5.2.17. I badly need your help. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your edit, but it won't work. Btw, the php version the web server the client is using is 5.2.17. That is why I am asking for a solution which will work on version 5.2.17.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33386/discussion-between-chi-rilo-and-pe-de-leao)

Comment: Hello Pé de Leão, I modified your solution a bit. I almost forgot that I am supposed to use `natsort()` instead. So I replaced `asort()` with `natsort()` and it perfectly worked. Merely, upvoting your answer does not suffice of how much thankful I am but thanks anyway. :)